# how to write store procedure - if(x = 1 or x = 2 or x = 3) set @ where = '.........'

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

i can't seem to find a way of writing the if statement like below in tsql.

```
if (x between 1 and 3) set @where = '........'
```

Comment: Could you explaine your problem in more detail ?

Comment: [Store Procedure in MS SQL DataBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms345415.aspx)  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add conditions within query, you can use case statement.

```
UPDATE tbl
SET salary = case 
               when salary between 100 and 300 then salary*10
               when salary between 300 and 500 then salary * 20
               else 0

from table tbl 
where salary is not null
```

if you are trying to write transact sql directly.

```
IF (@var in (select salary from table)) 
   && (@age between (select age from table))

begin
  print 'do something'
end
```